# undefined values error on values that are defined

Tags: opencv, undefined, identifier

I have a for loop like so

```
 for (int i = 0; i < circles->total; i++)
    {
         // round the floats to an int
         float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(circles, i);
         cv::Point center(cvRound(p[0]), cvRound(p[1]));
         int radius = cvRound(p[2]);
         int num_red = 0;
         //uchar* ptr;
         //ptr = cvPtr2D(img, center.y, center.x, NULL);
         //printf("B: %d G: %d R: %d\n", ptr[0],ptr[1],ptr[2]);
         CvScalar s;

         s = cvGet2D(img,center.y, center.x);//colour of circle
        printf("B: %f G: %f R: %f\n",s.val[0],s.val[1],s.val[2]);

        if (s.val[2]<=255 && s.val[2]>=230 && s.val[1]<=40 && s.val[1]>=0 && s.val[0] <=40 && s.val[0]>=0)
        {
            printf("Red Ball\n");
            num_red++;
        }
```

which is working. but later on in my code i tried to use the `s.val[]` and `num_red` like this

```
int count_red = 0;
int red_pot = 0;
if(s.val[2]<=255 && s.val[2]>=230 && s.val[1]<=40 && s.val[1]>=0 && s.val[0] <=40 && s.val[0]>=0)
    count_red ++;//count the reds detected
num_red - count_red = red_pot;//originally detected - whats left = whats potted
```

im getting undeclared identifier error for 's'. Left of .val must have class/struct and 'num_red' : undeclared identifier. I dont understand why the program doesnt can't read these values from above further down. anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create `s` inside the `for` loop. So as soon as the `for` loop terminates, `s` goes out of scope. You need to create a variable at a scope that includes every scope in which you intend to access it.

Comment: ah. so if i declare all say after "int main", should work then? thanks